# orginase the layout views in recyclerviews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 2 views in a `recyclerview`

```
  @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                       int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_IMAGE) {
            // create a new view
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            ImageViewHolder vh = new ImageViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        } else {
            // create a new view
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.childlayout, parent, false);
            // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
            TextViewHolder vh = new TextViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }
    }
```

my problem is withe layout design , I want the `rowlayout` to be above `childlayout` how to do that ?

this is main activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   // LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getDataSet());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration =
            new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
```

this is the UPDATED layouts

rowlayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/error" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Example application"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dip"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

childlayout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header_photo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/success" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Android Gig"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

With the recent layout I have the below wrong results

[image]

I want to have such result , please notice I am trying to add a title 'today' above the view
[image]

notice that there are scroller view horizontal

Comment: you mean you want to implement sorting for your items in recyclerview?

Comment: @thetonrifles when i run the app , the texts and the images are displayed wrong the texts are being above each other and the image also displayed wrong check my update question notice on left an image is displayed wrong i want the text and image displaye below the first layout .. did you understand me?

Comment: you mean it's a problem with layouts? ... I see you are using relative layout but not always defining relative position between views inside. In these cases maybe better to use LinearLayout. You want image on left and texts on the right, one above the other right?

Comment: @thetonrifles yes 1view text and images then below of it another view text and image ..i didnt know how to make the layout to be below of another layout .. how to position the views between view 1 and view 2

Comment: ok. I give you an answer in few time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this could help:

- **rowlayouts.xml**

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:padding="6dp">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/icon"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
          android:contentDescription="TODO"
          android:src="@drawable/logo" />

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:orientation="vertical">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/firstLine"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:text="Example application"
              android:textSize="16sp" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/secondLine"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="26dip"
              android:ellipsize="marquee"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:text="Description"
              android:textSize="12sp" />

      </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- **childlayout.xml**

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="10dp">

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/header_photo"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:src="@drawable/logo" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textc"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:text="Android Gig"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

Comment: the first view was displayed ,but the second is not displayed. i am trying to check something then if i didnt know how to solve it ill update my question

Comment: Ok, when you say "it is not displayed" you mean layout it is not used at all or layout is wrongly displayed?

Comment: layout are wrongly displayed 1 view is visible but the other one is not showing .. ll post an image of my result

Comment: @Moudiz I'm looking at updated screenshot. I'm not understanding very well which is final outcome you want. I mean... problem is the misalignment between texts and images?

Comment: give me one min please I am updating it will full explenation

Comment: ok... btw, in the meanwhile I made some updates to layout in my answer for better handling views alignments.

Comment: You mean that you need to add another label above the image in childlayout?

Comment: I'm asking because I don't understand if you need an additional text above each view, or just above one. If you need above each view, you just need to add a TextView above ImageView inside LinearLayout for childlayout.xml. If instead you want a fixed text "Today" you should probably use two RecyclerView and put a TextView (with "Today" label) between them.

Comment: If easier we can continue in chat, so that I can better support you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102134/discussion-between-thetonrifles-and-moudiz).

Comment: i asked a question related to my issue is it possible you check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113403/how-to-implement-2-or-more-recyiclerview-in-an-activity

Answer (score 0):

In your recyclerview adapter you can override a method called getItemViewType().
Notice that one off the parameters for onCreateViewHolder() is "int viewType". This viewType is got by the getItemViewType() method. Here you can write your logic to return a certain number for the type of view you want.

Eg: - 
    @Override

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    // you can return whatever integers you want
    //your logic goes here


    // Just as an example, return 0 or 1 depending on position.
    return position % 2 ;
}`
```

I wasn't sure what you meant by - "I want the rowlayout to be above childlayout". You can maybe return 0 for all views of type RowLayout and 1 for ChildLayout.